# How to find location value of any image..?

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS development. I got all photos of library using assetLibrary in an array. Now i want let user enter a longitude and latitude value , afterword check how many photos match there longitude and latitude values in 50 m range of users entered value.  And then display them in Collection view.. Please give help me with explanatory code.. ***thanks in advance***

Comment: Look here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Property_Keys

Comment: Thanks Retro.. But i checked that before but what i am searching is example so i can actually understand how it works..

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotosByLocation/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010136